# responsive navbar stacked with the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

i've got a problem that the navbar was stacked with the content. Does Anyone know How to fix the **nav-bar?** and why the navbar is stacked, help me. i was try to fix it with **z-index** but not working...  plz help me, i was frustated. i want the navbar is not stacked and the background is #fff.

[stacked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqakK.png)

```js
        const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
        let nav = document.querySelector('.menu ul')
        burger.addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.classList.toggle('change');
            nav.classList.toggle('open');
        });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: .5s;
}

:root {
    --body-color: #fff;
    --main-color: #1c1c3c;
    --text-color: #fff;
    --red-color: #800000;
    --semi-white: #ccc;

}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.body{ 
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100vh
}
/*Nav And Header*/
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    align-items: center;
    background:#fff;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.logo {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

header ul li a:hover {
    transition: .5s;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 525;
    color: var(--red-color);
}

header ul li a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -3px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #800000;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: right;
}

header ul li a:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}

/*Hamburger Setting*/
.burger {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    background-color: var(--red-color);
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: var(--red-color);
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    background-color: var(--red-color);
}

/*TextBox code*/
.text-box {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.text-box h1,
.text-box span {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 46px;
}
.red-btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    color: var(--main-color);
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 15px 34px;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: var(--body-color);
    border: 1px solid var(--red-color);
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.red-btn:hover{
    background: var(--red-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
/*Code Of Dashboard*/

/*This is responsive code*/

@media(max-width:920px) {
    .text-box h1 {
        font-size: 190%;
    }


.text-box p {
    margin: 20px 0 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--main-color);
}
    .menu ul {
        position: absolute;
        height: 40vh;
        top: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#fff;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        padding: auto;
        top: 100px;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .burger {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .menu ul.open {
        position: fixed;
        opacity: 5;
        visibility:visible;
        left:0;
        z-index: 99;
        transition: 1s;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>BeHealthy.com</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#"><img src="" alt="logo" style="width: 55px;">
            <p style="float: right; padding: 22px 0 ;" class="logo"> Lo<span
                    style="color:#800000 ;font-size:1em; font-weight: 500;">go</span></p>
        </a>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color:#800000 ;">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tumbal.html" target="_blank">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Artikel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Konsultasi</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="text-box">
            <h1>Lorem <span style="color: #800000;font-size: 100%;">Ipsum!</span>
                <h1>
                    <p><b>Healthy First!</b>,Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium culpa debitis porro, neque consequatur, est quisquam nisi explicabo error, nostrum iste id. Incidunt, laudantium rem totam nisi itaque aperiam amet?
                        </b>BeHealthy<b>.</p>
                    <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:550;">#StayHealthy</span>
                    <br>
                    <a href="indeex.html" class="red-btn" target="_blank">this is button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please use below css. I have made changes only css file. Hope it may helpful to you.

```js
      const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
        let nav = document.querySelector('.menu ul')
        burger.addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.classList.toggle('change');
            nav.classList.toggle('open');
        });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: .5s;
}

:root {
    --body-color: #fff;
    --main-color: #1c1c3c;
    --text-color: #fff;
    --red-color: #800000;
    --semi-white: #ccc;

}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.body{ 
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100vh;
}
/*Nav And Header*/
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    align-items: center;
    background:#fff;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

header ul li a:hover {
    transition: .5s;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 525;
    color: var(--red-color);
}

header ul li a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -3px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #800000;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: right;
}

header ul li a:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}

/*Hamburger Setting*/
.burger {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    background-color: var(--red-color);
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: var(--red-color);
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    background-color: var(--red-color);
}

/*TextBox code*/
.text-box {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.text-box h1,
.text-box span {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 46px;
}
.red-btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    color: var(--main-color);
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 15px 34px;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: var(--body-color);
    border: 1px solid var(--red-color);
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.red-btn:hover{
    background: var(--red-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}
/*Code Of Dashboard*/

/*This is responsive code*/

@media(max-width:920px) {
    .text-box h1 {
        font-size: 190%;
    }


.text-box p {
    margin: 20px 0 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--main-color);
}
    .menu ul {
        position: absolute;
        height: calc(100vh - 80px);
        top: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#fff;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        padding: auto;
        top: 80px;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 3;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .burger {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .menu ul.open {
        position: fixed;
        opacity: 5;
        visibility:visible;
        left:0;
        z-index: 99;
        transition: 1s;
        overflow: auto;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>BeHealthy.com</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#"><img src="" alt="logo" style="width: 55px;">
            <p style="float: right; padding: 22px 0 ;" class="logo"> Lo<span
                    style="color:#800000 ;font-size:1em; font-weight: 500;">go</span></p>
        </a>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color:#800000 ;">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tumbal.html" target="_blank">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Artikel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Konsultasi</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="text-box">
            <h1>Lorem <span style="color: #800000;font-size: 100%;">Ipsum!</span>
                <h1>
                    <p><b>Healthy First!</b>,Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium culpa debitis porro, neque consequatur, est quisquam nisi explicabo error, nostrum iste id. Incidunt, laudantium rem totam nisi itaque aperiam amet?
                        </b>BeHealthy<b>.</p>
                    <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:550;">#StayHealthy</span>
                    <br>
                    <a href="indeex.html" class="red-btn" target="_blank">this is button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```